Title of a Romantic UFO movie ending in Paris?
Can anyone help me with the title of a movie? Probably from early 00s and maybe shown on Amazon Prime. As best as I can recall, the storyline centres on
a young scientist(male)  working on a project (maybe to do with antigravity or energy generation), walking in the woods, meets a pretty young woman who's just landed from a UFO which he doesn't see. They meet on several more occasions in his town, where she is, I think, an artist. Eventually he learns that she is an alien and her mother is summoning her back to the spaceship, and he decides to go with her.  At the end of the movie we see them both in Paris, in front of the Eiffel Tower, as her mother arrives in her spaceship to become the ambassador to Earth.
